# AWS Amplify does not create Bucket in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, next.js, aws-amplify

Hello guys i'am trying to deploy my Next.js app on Amplify connecting my GitHub repository. Now if try to deploy it on server us-east-1 (default server), AWS creates all services (S3 bucket, CloudFront and Amplify) and this works. Now if try to do the same in Europe with server eu-south-1, AWS creates only the Amplify service without creating any S3 Bucket and CloudFront services. So i get the error 404 not found, with no site (blank screen) because there is no site on S3, if i change the redirect to 200 i can see the AccessDenied error. In S3 and CloudFront there is no service linked to this app deployed in Europe, there is only the one uploaded in USA.

Now i think that it's a policy problem, but really i don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Hi @Antonio De Luca did you ever solved this?

Comment: I'm having this same problem, amplify is not creating the cloudfront distribution

Comment: I'm back again. I solved this problem before but I forgot how I did it